# Do Loop running another macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Im new to this and fairly new to VBA.

Been trying my hand at it and found that I can sort out looping at all.

I have a long macro to run it finds a workbook and copies the data into a mail merge on word. I cant find a way to loop this macro as im using the value from A2 to find the file and need it to loop through column A.

Any help would be gratefully received.

this is what i have so far.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

varCellvalue = Range("A2").Value

Workbooks.Open("Y:\SHARED_SERVICES\File storage\" & varCellvalue & "\" & varCellvalue &     "_preparation v3.xls").Activate

ActiveWindow.Visible = True

Range("A2:AY2").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.Close

Windows("Test.xlsm").Activate
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

WordApp.Visible = False
 WordApp.documents.Open("C:\Users\letter Merge trial.docm").ActivateWordApp.Run     "MailMergeLetter"
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("Y:\SHARED_SERVICES\File storage\" & varCellvalue & "\Letter_" & varCellvalue & ".doc")
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\Letters to print\Letter_" & varCellvalue & ".doc")
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
WordApp.documents("C:\Users\Spreadsheets to merge\ letter Merge trial.docm").Activate
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close

WordApp.documents.Open("C:\Users\Spreadsheets to merge\ATIP.docx").Activate
WordApp.Run "MailMergeATIP"
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("Y:\SHARED_SERVICES\File storage\" & varCellvalue & "\ATIP_" & varCellvalue & ".doc")
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Letters to print\ATIP_" & varCellvalue & ".doc")
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
WordApp.documents("C:\Users\Spreadsheets to merge\ATIP.docx").Activate
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close

Windows("Test.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming column A contains folder names and each folder contains the same file (`_preparation v3.xls`) name.

Here is one method for looping through a range of values.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    'Change your range according to your list size
    Set rng = Range("A2:A10")

    For Each cell In rng
        varCellvalue = cell

        'Put the rest of your code here for looping
        '....

    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Portland Runner, that works like a dream. You've saved me a heap of time.

Comment: Glad to help you out.  Please accept this as answered so that the post can be shown as complete. Thanks.